# Natural equivalence of Dehn and spherical twist of Fukaya category

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, fukaya-category

We consider the setup of Seidel's book. Let $(M,\omega)$ be an exact symplectic manifold with $2c_1=0$. Seidel defines the Fukaya category $\text{Fuk}(M)$ of $M$.

A Lagrangian sphere $L\subset M$, equipped with a brane structure, defines an object of $\text{Fuk}(M)$. There are two twist functors associated to $L$. The first is the autoequivalence of the Fukaya category associated to the Dehn twist on $L$. The second is the spherical twist functor of the spherical object $L\in \text{Fuk}(M)$. It is shown by Seidel, see corollary III.17.17, that pointwise both twist functors are equivalent.

**Question:** Has it been shown in general that there is an equivalence of functors between both twist functors? Have counterexamples been found?

**What I know so far:** In remark III.17.22, Seidel writes that ongoing work of Wehrheim-Woodward on Lagrangian correspondences is supposed to show that this equivalence is natural. I don't know if this indeed follows from their papers, at least it is not explicitly mentioned. Using very different ideas, the equivalence of functors is, as far as I understand, established in some examples of complex dimension 1 by S. Opper in [arXiv:1904.04859](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.04859.pdf).

Comment: I doubt this is the first proof, but in the case where $M$ is Weinstein I think this follows from Theorem 1.2 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.02317. In the non-Weinstein case something similar should be possible by identifying the semiorthogonal gluing as a full subcategory of $\mathcal{FS}(W_L^2)$, where $W_L^2$ is the square of the Lefschetz fibration with vanishing cycle $L$, but I haven't worked it out.

Comment: I don't really understand, could you be more specific why Theorem 1.2 is relevant for my question?

Comment: Consider the Lefschetz fibration $W_L$ with fiber $M$ and single vanishing cycle $L$. Then $\mathcal{FS}(W_L)$ is the ground ring $\mathbb k$, and the cup/Orlov functor is the coYoneda map $\hom(L, \cdot)$. It follows that the dual cotwist of the cup functor is the algebraic twist along $L$, while the monodromy is Dehn twist along $L$ (with a shift).

Comment: What does the word "pointwise" in "pointwise both twist functors are equivalent" mean?

Comment: A functor assigns objects to objects and morphisms to morphisms. Two functors are pointwise equivalent if they assing to each object equivalent objects.